# Ubuntu 20.04 multi-monitor setup problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my desktop that has 4 monitors, 3 of which are desired to work in portrait mode.

However, to my utter surprise, I can't seem to make the settings work. I tried NVIDIA X server , arandr , xrandr to change settings .. but nothing survives the reboot.

The displays tab on GNOME settings is the scariest, whenever I try to apply the desired settings 1-2 monitors get disabled and then arent detected until I head to the NVIDIA X server. And the activities bar is distributed to 2 screens when it should be only on the primary monitor of choice.

Anyone else facing the same thing? If anyone knows a way around it, please do suggest and guide as to what could be done to make the experience smoother

Note - everything works like a breeze on windows